# Converting HYPERLINK() - to text with an underlying link

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have a column with many (hundreds) of rows, each with a HYPERLINK formula, e.g.

```
=HYPERLINK("https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/provider-view/99999", "99999")
```

How can I convert all into a cells that contain the text - but with an underlying link (as in with CTRL-K), e.g., [99999](https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/provider-view/99999)

Thanks!

Comment: If I correctly understand, you want an adjacent cell to display the URL that's embedded in the formula. I think you can create a short UDF in VBA, give it a name such as "GetURL", then use that in a formula.

Comment: Hi Isolated. I should have been clearer. I mean that the cell's content would be 99999 and that the link should be embedded, as with CTRL-K.

Comment: Hmmm. I think a picture of your issue would help. When you use a formula like that, then it should automatically just show 99999. If you are seeing the actual formula, then I suspect your cells are formatted as text. You could format the column as General, then copy the column and paste into notepad. Then copy out of notepad and paste back into your excel column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, the problem is not the security setting of the Excel for Mac but the hyperlink formula was composed with 2 cell references; the display text, and the link.

The VBA function to insert / replace a hyperlinked to a cell is as of the following.

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=current_range, Address:=address_string, TextToDisplay:=display_string
```

In your situation, you have to replace current_range, address_string, and display_string in the VBA syntax.

In my above example, since we are using a For loop to loop through all the cells in selection, you can leave it as *current_range*.

For the *address_string*, and *display_string*, you will feed the function with the cell location of those two on your spreadhseet. Since your spreadsheet has the address string stored in two separate columns, you want to reference to the column by either using the familiar cell reference format, Range("$C" & current_range.row) format, or use the offset method, which involve in counting the index of the column. Example, current_range.offset(0, -10).value. The -10 in the offset is how many column you want to move left from your current_range.

Note, it is important to add the .value at the back of your cell reference so it's getting the data (String) stored in the cell instead of the potential formula in the cell.

Comment: Hi Harry. Still the same. In order not to take up unnecessary space on this page, can we move to direct communication? My email address is lipson.nathan@gmail.com.

Comment: Have you also checked your Excel to see if it's blocking all Macro?
Check your Excel Options, Trust Center, Macro Settings, and make sure it's at "Disable all macros with notification" so at least you have a chance to enable macros on a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

Create this macro.

```
Sub convert_hyperlink_formula_to_hyperlink_cell()
Dim address_string As String, display_string As String
Dim current_range As Range

For Each current_range In Selection
    address_string = Mid(current_range.Formula, 13, InStr(1, current_range.Formula, ",") - 14)
    display_string = current_range.value
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=current_range, Address:=address_string, TextToDisplay:=display_string
Next current_range
End Sub
```

Select the range of your Hyperlink formulas then run the macro. That should convert the hyperlink formulas to actual hyperlinked cells.

Please try this sample file.

[Convert Hyperlink Sample File.xlsm](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ar0IX30aIfIPmmS4StOOrO9cVr0l?e=HBO76u)

I have made a copy of your posted formula, and pasted a few lines in the sample file. The macro is already setup in the Excel file for your to test.

Comment: Hi Harry. Thanks! I have pretty much zero experience with Macros. I this I was able to create the macro, but when I tried to run it (after marking a few cells), nothing happened. I tried to find a way to add a screenshot of the macro's edit screen into this comment but couldn't find a way. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

For those that aren't VBA/Macro savvy, a quick and dirty way to do this is to copy the column with the Hyperlink function... and paste it into MS Word.  Then paste it back to Excel.

Is it efficient? Heck no.  Does it work?  Yes!